# How to get row number?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, row, indexof

I have `DataTable` and i need to clear all empty columns. So here is code example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
{
      if (table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().All(r => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r[i].ToStringOrNull())))
      {
             table.Columns.RemoveAt(i--);
      }
}
```

Question : How can i get row Number in `If-statement` ?

Thanks.

Comment: are you looking for row number based some in the data table?

Comment: Use `for` instead extension method `All`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "row number", you mean the index of a `Row` object in the `Rows` collection, then you can't get that directly from the `Row` object. You can, as suggested in Vlad's comment, use something like this instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    if (Enumerable.Range(0, table.Rows.Count).All(
        j => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tables.Rows[j][i].ToStringOrNull())))
    {
        table.Columns.RemoveAt(i--);
    }
}
```

That said, it seems to me that it would be better to process the data such that you visit each row only once. This should at the very least improve data locality, and in some scenarios could significantly improve performance. E.g.:

```
bool[] keepColumn = new bool[table.Columns.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if (!keepColumn[j] &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(table.Columns[j].ToStringOrNull()))
        {
            keepColumn[j] = true;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = table.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (!keepColumn[i])
    {
        table.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

It's obviously a bit more verbose, but IMHO it would be worth it in this case, because it's processing the data in their natural organization (i.e. tables are naturally rows that have columns, as opposed to columns that have rows).